# std::enable_if for two different methods implementation (4 different cases)

Tags: c++, templates

I need to implement two different methods for const and non-const types. I have manage to write working code but I do not understand why some of its flavors are OK and some of them are not.

Here is simplified example and I would like to know why #1 works but #2 is not, and same regarding #3 vs #4:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class X {
public:
    // #1 - works
    template<typename B = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<B>::value, int>::type = 0>
    void foo() {std::cout << "CONST" << std::endl;}
    template<typename B = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<B>::value == false, int>::type = 0>
    void foo() {std::cout << "NON-CONST" << std::endl;}

    // #2 - does not work "no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::enable_if<false, int>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable this declaration"
//    template<typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
//    void foo() {std::cout << "CONST" << std::endl;}
//    template<typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<T>::value == false, int>::type = 0>
//    void foo() {std::cout << "NON-CONST" << std::endl;}

    // #3 - works
//    template<typename B = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<B>::value>::type>
//    void foo() {std::cout << "CONST" << std::endl;}
//    template<typename B = T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<B>::value == false>::type * = nullptr>
//    void foo() {std::cout << "NON-CONST" << std::endl;}

    // # 4 - does not work - "class member cannot be redeclared"
//    template<typename B = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<B>::value>::type>
//    void foo() {std::cout << "CONST" << std::endl;}
//    template<typename B = T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<B>::value == false>::type>
//    void foo() {std::cout << "NON-CONST" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    X<int> v;
    X<const int> vConst;

    v.foo();
    vConst.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Even if there is a better approach to solve my problem I would really like to understand why enable_if works like it (not) works in presented examples.

Comment: Just a matter of style, but prefer having `!condition` instead of `condition == false`...

Comment: @Aconcagua: sure, usually I use `!condition` but unfortunately templates code can be so complicated that `condition == false` is much more visible/readable for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't SFINAE (enable\_if) work for member functions of a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953248/why-doesnt-sfinae-enable-if-work-for-member-functions-of-a-class-template)

Comment: Or, likely a better duplicate match: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6972368/580083

Comment: Side note: You might cover the issue more easily with constexpr if inside a non-template function (just for the case you are not aware of...).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`#2` doesn't works as your have hard failure as `T` is fixed by the class.

so you really have

```
template<typename std::enable_if<true, int>::type = 0>  // -> template<int = 0>  void foo();
void foo();

template<typename std::enable_if<false, int>::type = 0> // Hard error failure
void foo();
```

For `#4`, default template value/type are not part of the signature, so once those removed, you have

```
template <typename B, typename> void foo() {std::cout << "CONST" << std::endl;}
template <typename B, typename> void foo() {std::cout << "NON-CONST" << std::endl;}
```

Same method with several definitions: you break ODR.

For `#3`, it would be:

```
template<typename B, typename>
void foo();

template<typename B, typename std::enable_if<std::is_const<B>::value == false>::type *>
void foo();
```

which are different.

Comment: Perhaps interesting at #3 to illustrate the difference more clearly: *if* second `foo` *is* enabled, it would get to `<typename B, void*>`

Comment: @Aconcagua: but signature **differs** before that substitution, for example [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0776478b57a35083) produces ambiguous call (instead of ODR violation, as your sentence would suggest).

Comment: Don't see why my comment would suggest ODR violation, my intention *was* to make the differing signature more obvious...

Comment: I meant that `typename <typename T, std::enable_if_t<cond<T>, int>> voif f()` and `template <typename T, int> void f()` are 2 different signatures, even if after substitution, they result in same.

Comment: Ah, I see... got misguided by your emphasis ("but signature differs even *before* that substitution" would have been more obvious), but interesting aspect...