# SFINAE with Templated class Member functions

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

I'm trying to learn about SFINAE and came across a problem while trying to apply it to template class member functions. Thanks to [Why doesn't SFINAE (enable_if) work for member functions of a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953248/why-doesnt-sfinae-enable-if-work-for-member-functions-of-a-class-template) I was able to setup a basic example([Run online](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e342b821a69e5e4)):

```
template<typename T>
class Foo{
    public:
    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<U, int>::value && !std::is_same<U, float>::value,int> = 0>
    void sfinae() { // Foo<anything else>
        std::cout << "sfinae default" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, int>::value,int> = 0>
    void sfinae() { // Foo<int>
        std::cout << "sfinae int" << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, float>::value,int> = 0>
    void sfinae() { // Foo<float>
        std::cout << "sfinae float" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I had two follow up questions to this:
1. **How can I separate the declaration and definition of the member functions?**
I tried something like below for the definition:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<U, int>::value && !std::is_same<U, float>::value,int> = 0>
    void Foo<T>::sfinae() { // Foo<anything else>
        std::cout << "sfinae default" << std::endl;
    }
```

But this gives a compilation error.
2. The catch-all default case(which prints sfinae-default) has to currently be written as `not(type1, type2,...)` which can potentially be huge. Is there a shorter/cleaner solution possible?

**Edit**:
Based on the answer by @Jans, here is a [corrected solution](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3360506fa4e3d3f).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *out of line* definition you remove the default arguments, they are taken from declarations:

```
template <class T>
template <typename U, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<U, int>::value && !std::is_same<U, float>::value,int>>
void Foo<T>::sfinae() { // Foo<anything else>
    std::cout << "sfinae default" << std::endl;
}
```

the same for the others

> The catch-all default case(which prints sfinae-default) has to currently be written as `not(type1, type2,...)` which can potentially be huge. Is there a shorter/cleaner solution possible?

For this you need to add an extra parameter to rank the overloads giving the lowest rank to the catch-all one, this is usually done using the fact that the ellipsis parameter is not better than any other parameter type:

```
template <typename U = T>
void sfinae(...);

template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, int>::value,int> = 0>
void sfinae(int);

template <typename U = T, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<U, float>::value,int> = 0>
void sfinae(int);

Foo<char>{}.sfinae(0); // select the catch-all
```

What this means is that since `...` is worse than any other parameter (`int` is better than `...`), the overload `sfinae(...)` is only considered if the other two can't be called, i.e if they SFINAE.

Comment: Thanks I can confirm this is working! That said: (1) Is it not possible without the extra "int" parameter? and (2) Could you add some details to your answer about how the ranking works exactly?