# Kindly explain problem in following function template declaration (Underlying cause)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

In following code, could anyone explain why do I get following error:
"error: no type named ‘type’ in `struct std::enable_if<false, double>`

According to my understanding of enable_if_t, there should not be any problem at compile time if I am not using function p. It should simply not get generated for simple types.

But when I change condition to `!is_class_v<T>`, it works fine for simple types but then it stops working for class types.

```
template<typename T>
class Smart_class
{
    public:        
        enable_if_t<is_class_v<T>, T> p(T t)
        {            
            
        };
};

void f()
{
    Smart_class<double> a;
}
```

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [Why doesn't SFINAE (enable_if) work for member functions of a class template?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30953248/580083).

Comment: @DanielLangr this is so common mistake, that there should be some catch-phrase for it. Something like "Declaration is not substitution"

Comment: Thanks Daniel Langr. I understood the cause.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I don't think this is a duplicate. That question asked why SFINAE does not work as expected. Here, the problem is somewhere else — that the declaration of `p` is instantiated.

Comment: @Daniel Langr the only point of `enable_if_t` is to prevent substitution  to happen. but at context of function declaration substitution already happened when class was implicitly instantiated and results in syntax error (there is no nested definition in `enable_if` present). if "p"  itself was a template, that won't happen. That's essentially is a failed attempt to use SFINAE, it looks like `p` was meant for types that are classes only

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I understand your point. Just based on this sentence: _"According to my understanding of `enable_if_t`, there should not be any problem at compile time if I am not using function `p`."_ — I think the OP asked about something else.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [temp.inst/3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#inst-3.1):

> The **implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations**, but not of the definitions, **of the non-deleted class member functions**...

This is your case, the **declaration** of `p` member function is instantiated and it refers to the non-existing return type.