# enable_if with is_move_constructible allows non-movable types, but requires does not

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, enable-if

I have a non-movable structure and a templated class in which I want to have a function that exists only when the type is movable (using enable_if and type_traits). However, it seems that despite std::is_move_constructible_v returns false, the function still exists and can be executed. However, when I changed the code to use requires clause, everything works as intended.
Why is that?

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

class NonMovable{
    public:
        NonMovable(const NonMovable&) = default;
        NonMovable(NonMovable&&) = delete;
        
        NonMovable& operator =(const NonMovable&) = default;
        NonMovable& operator = (NonMovable&&) = delete;
        
        NonMovable() = default;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo{
    template<typename = std::enable_if<std::is_move_constructible_v<T>,bool>>
    void foo(T&& t){ // allowed
        // ...
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo{
    void foo(T&& t) requires std::is_move_constructible_v<T>{ // not allowed
        // ...
    }
};

int main(){
    NonMovable nonMovable;
    Foo<NonMovable> x;
    std::cout << std::is_move_constructible_v<NonMovable> << "\n"; // 0
    x.foo(std::move(nonMovable));
}
```

Comment: Looks like you meant `enable_if_t`, not `enable_if`.

Comment: Do you only want to disable that constructor, not the whole class instance?

Comment: @NathanPierson thank you, that was the case

Comment: @TedLyngmo intention was to disable just the function. I managed to do this with `requires` clause. 'enable_if_t` disables the whole class.

Comment: And so it is _t or  ::type missing ... so typo level problem.

Comment: For using SFINAE to disable _just_ the member function and not the entire class, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953248/why-doesnt-sfinae-enable-if-work-for-member-functions-of-a-class-template).

Comment: @capi1500 I just wanted to make sure (and I thought `foo` was `Foo`s constructor - I didn't see that it was a regular member function until now). I added an answer to what I think you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to disable that `foo` function for non move constructible types, you could make the template parameter a dependent type:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo{
    template<class U = T, class = std::enable_if_t<
                                      std::is_same_v<T,U>&&
                                      std::is_move_constructible_v<U>>>
    void foo(T&&){ // not allowed
        // ...
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9MvP75vxP)

Comment: I think you might need to do `std::is_move_constructible_v<std::remove_cvref_t<U>>` or include `std::is_same_v<U, T>` in the `enable_if` or something to disable things like allowing the creation of `foo` for `U = NonMovable&`. Concepts and requirements really are an advance...

Comment: @NathanPierson Good point. `is_same` added

Comment: Actually the issue that came up for me in my messing around was when I had made the signature `void foo(U&&)` instead of `void foo(T&&)`, which leaves more room for the compiler to deduce the value of `U`. Still, since the intent seems to be that the member function shouldn't actually be templated separately from the enclosing struct, it's worth locking down weird instantiations of it.

Comment: @NathanPierson I actually don't know if having `U` or `T` in `foo(x&&)` makes a difference (after I added your idea with `std::is_same`).. Is there some corner case that makes `U` preferable here?

Comment: It definitely makes a difference if you don't have `is_same`, but I don't know which is preferable. Indeed I think using `T` as you did actually is preferable. The test calling code I was looking at was `x.foo(nonMovable);` instead of `x.foo(std::move(nonMovable));`. Using `U` instead of `T` meant that it actually successfully instantiated because it `U&&` in that context is a forwarding reference, to an lvalue `NonMovable&`, which is apparently move-constructible. Using `T&&` instead of `U&&` seems to shut that down. I think after the `is_same` it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @NathanPierson Oh, right ... the forwarding reference in this context totally slipped my mind. Many thanks! It's not that it becomes move-constructible in that context but it could be forwarded to a copy constructor I guess

Answer (score 0):

As @Nathan Pierson mentioned in the comment, there should be `enable_if_t` instead of `enable_if`