# Why SFINAE does not work in the following case and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, sfinae

I'm reading the [C++ Programming Language, 4th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840) by [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) and in Chapter 28 about metaprogramming in Section 28.4.4 there is a code similar to the following example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

struct substitution_failure {};

template <typename T>
struct substitution_succeeded : std::true_type {};

template <>
struct substitution_succeeded<substitution_failure> : std::false_type {};

double f(double x)
{
  return x;
}

template <typename T>
class get_f_result
{
  template <typename X>
  static auto check(const X& x) -> decltype(f(x));

  static substitution_failure check(...);

public:
  using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};

template <typename T>
struct has_f : substitution_succeeded<typename get_f_result<T>::type> {};

template <typename T>
constexpr bool has_f_v()
{
  return has_f<T>::value;
}

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  template <typename = std::enable_if_t<has_f_v<T>()>>
  T foo(const T& t)
  {
    return f(t);
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo<std::string> foo;
  return 0;
}
```

I expect thanks to the SFINAE the example to compile successfully after the `foo` method of the `Foo` class is never called, but it compiles only on MSVC and refuses to compile on GCC and Clang with the following error:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >'
 2611 |     using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
```

Why the example compiles only on MSVC and how to fix it to compile successfully also on GCC and Clang?

Comment: Might be an MSVC error where it's supposed to figure out the default value for the type argument of `Foo::foo` immediately even if `foo` isn't instantiated but it doesn't do so.

Comment: @Nathan MSVC compiles without error or warning even if you add another member to `Foo` and actually call that. (I also thought that it may be optimizing-out the whole `foo` instance, but that isn't it.)

Comment: There is no SFINAE in `Foo::foo` because `T` is already fixed by `Foo` itself. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30953248/why-doesnt-sfinae-enable-if-work-for-member-functions-of-a-class-template).

Comment: @Evg Cool! Using `template <typename U = T, typename = std::enable_if_t<has_f_v<U>()>>` (and making the return type and arg for `foo` a `U`) works on clang.