How can the template arguments of a default constructor be different from those of the class in C++?
When reading the implementation of std::pair in gcc source code, I found one of the default constructors as below:
  template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
    struct pair
    : public __pair_base<_T1, _T2>
    {
      typedef _T1 first_type;    ///< The type of the `first` member
      typedef _T2 second_type;   ///< The type of the `second` member

      _T1 first;                 ///< The first member
      _T2 second; 
...
      template <typename _U1 = _T1,
                typename _U2 = _T2,
                typename enable_if<__and_<
                                     __is_implicitly_default_constructible<_U1>,
                                     __is_implicitly_default_constructible<_U2>>
                                   ::value, bool>::type = true>
      constexpr pair()
      : first(), second() { }
...
}

My question is, when using the default ctor to construct an object, it's also the time to instantiate an object of the class as below:
std::pair<int, double> p;

How can _U1 be different from _T1? Thank you guys.

I guess that template parameters _U1 and _U2 exist only because of SFINAE, which implements this constraint: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/pairs#pair-5.

Template parameters of the constructor don't need to be related to those of the class. This particular constructor expects that the user does not specify the parameters at all because the corresponding constructor in the standard is not a template. The parameters are needed to implement the provision that This constructor participates in overload resolution if and only if std::is_default_constructible_v<T1> and std::is_default_constructible_v<T2> are both true.

@DanielLangr Hi, this idea sounds inspiring. Would you mind talking more about it in details?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Hi. I haven't understood it all. So why isn't it just like template <typename = typename enable_if<       std::is_default_constructible<U1>::value &&       std::is_default_constructible<U2>::value>::type>?

@Ethan Read, e.g., this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30953248/580083

It wouldn't work because SFINAE wouldn't be triggered in this case, and a hard error would occur instead.

@Ethan SFINAE requires substitution failure in so-called immediate context, which does not happen in the code in your previous comment. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/temp#deduct.general-8.sentence-5.

OT: Note that with concepts, the default constructor no longer needs to be a template: https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/dafd63d7c5cddce1e00803606e742d75927b1a1e/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_pair.h#L346.

@DanielLangr I see it. The critical point is that "SFINAE only works for function templates". There are no function template parameters in my previous wrong version. Thank you a lot.

It can't1. By defaulting the constructor template arguments _U1 and _U2 to the class template parameters _T1 and _T2, there is scope for the substitution failure with the third (unnamed) non-type template parameter.
This is the mechanism by which that overload isn't available when either _T1 or _T2 isn't implicitly default constructable.

Because this is a constructor, there isn't anywhere where _U1 and _U2 can be explicitly specified, so the only source is the default. Normal function templates can have explicit parameters, e.g. std::pair<int, double> pair; pair.operator=<char, float>({'a', 1.0f})

